# How to generate asset IDs in Rails 3 to control cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cache-control, asset-management

In Rails, when serving static files, you get an `asset ID` that's appended to the URL, e.g.,

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1300371955" ...
<link href="/stylesheets/custom.css?1299690788" ...
```

This way, the URL of a static file is changed if the file’s timestamp is changed and browsers automatically request the new file.

I saw that by using the helper methods for including static assets --- `stylesheet_link_tag`, `javascript_include_tag` and `image_tag` --- Rails automatically adds timestamps to all references to those files.

How can I implement something similar for other assets that don't have such helper methods 
*e.g.,* `.swf` files?

(*Does this "strategy" to force the re-download have a name; if so, what is it called?*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rails method that appends the timestamp to assets is called rails_asset_id, and is defined in ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.  Though it is a private method, it can be accessed in a helper to generate one for your custom tags like so:

```
def swf_param_tag(path)
  asset_id = rails_asset_id(path)
  "<param name='movie' value='#{path}?#{asset_id}'/>"
end
```

It needs you to pass in the path, because it then calls File.mtime(path).to_i.to_s on it to get the last modified time on it.

There is further explanation about what the asset tag buys you here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

@Unixmonkey: your solution works very well.

As an alternative there's also the **[swf_fu](https://github.com/marcandre/swf_fu)** plugin:

> treat your Adobe Flash swf files like any other asset (images, javascripts, etc...) and embed them using SWFObject 2.2

that has **asset tagging** built-in.